# sklearn.datasets.make_classification fails to generate balanced classes

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to use `make_classification` from the sklearn library to generate data for classification tasks, and I want each class to have exactly 4 samples.

If the number of classes if less than 19, the behavior is normal.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs, make_classification
import numpy as np
data = make_classification(n_samples=76, n_features=5, n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, 
                           n_classes=19, n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=None, flip_y=0, class_sep=1.0, 
                           shuffle=False, random_state=101)
print(data[1])
[ 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5
  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11
 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17
 18 18 18 18]
```

However, if the number of classes if equal to or more than 20, the first class would have 5 samples, and the last class would have only 3 samples, which is not balanced.

```
data = make_classification(n_samples=80, n_features=5, n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, 
                           n_classes=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=None, flip_y=0, class_sep=1.0, 
                           shuffle=False, random_state=101)
print(data[1])
[ 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  5  5  5
  5  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 11 11 11
 11 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 17 17 17
 17 18 18 18 18 19 19 19]
```

When checking the documentation, I found that the `weight` argument is controlling the proportion of the `classes`:

> `weights` : list of floats or None (default=None)
>
> The proportions of samples assigned to each class. If None, then
>   classes are balanced. Note that if len(weights) == n_classes - 1, then
>   the last class weight is automatically inferred. More than n_samples
>   samples may be returned if the sum of weights exceeds 1.

Therefore, I try to input the proportion explicitly with the following code.

```
data = make_classification(n_samples=80, n_features=5, n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, 
                           n_classes=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=list(np.ones(20)), flip_y=0, class_sep=1.0, 
                           shuffle=False, random_state=101)
print(data[1])
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Yet, the classes generated are completely wrong.

I am not sure why this function behaves like this. How to ensure balanced classes when the `n_classes` is greater or equal than 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though its not explicitly mentioned and is confusing, the parameter `weights` require "proportions" of samples. It does not convert numbers to proportions automatically.

So if total number of samples = 80 and you want to assign 40 samples to class 1, the proportion becomes `0.5`.

But, you are providing proportions as:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,.................., 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Thats the source of error. The method takes 1.0 for first class (0 in your case) and ignores all others.

Doing this:

```
n_classes = 20
weights=list(np.ones(20)/n_classes)  <== Making proportions correct

data = make_classification(n_samples=80, n_features=5, n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, 
                           n_classes=n_classes, n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=weights, flip_y=0, class_sep=1.0, 
                           shuffle=False, random_state=101)
```

returns correctly:

```
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,
        4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,
        8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12,
       12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16,
       17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19])
```

The last line:

> More than n_samples samples may be returned if the sum of weights exceeds 1.

seems to add to confusion.

When you pass `1.0` as proportions for all classes, then it should have returned 80*20 = 1600 samples, 80 with each class.

But its not doing so. It internally generates the samples correctly, but then only gives the first 80 samples back (as defined by `n_samples` param). Thats why you only get a single class (0) back in the generated data. You should post this as an issue on their page at github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues